# Existence of $\{a_{n}\}$ satisfying certain properties

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, inequality, continuity

[True/False]

Let $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a homeomorphism such that $f(0)=0$ and $ | f-Id | \nless M$ for any $ M>0$. Then there exists a sequence $\{ a_{n} \}$ of real numbers such that,
$$(1) | a_{n+1}| > |a_{n} |  
 ~{}~{} \forall n\in \mathbb{N}, | a_{n} | \to \infty$$
$$~{}~{}(2) | f(a_{n+1})-a_{n+1}| > |f(a_{n})-a_{n} |~{}~~{}\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, |f(a_{n}) -a_{n} | \to \infty$$
I could prove this result considering $(f-Id)$ as homeomorphism but couldn't show this result when $f$ is a homeomorphism.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can inductively construct a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$  such that

$$
|a_{n+1}| \geq |a_n| + 1, |(f-id)(a_{n+1})| \geq |(f-id)(a_{n})| +1 \tag{3}
$$

Here is how : choose $a_1$ arbitrarily (for example $a_1=0$). Suppose that $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ have already been constructed. Let $K=|a_n|+1$.

Since $|f-Id|$ is not bounded on ${\mathbb R}$ and bounded on $[-K,K]$, it is not bounded on ${\mathbb R} \setminus [-K,K]$. So there must be a $x\in {\mathbb R} \setminus [-K,K]$ such that $|(f-id)(x)|\geq |(f-id)(a_{n})| +1$, and then you can take $a_{n+1}=x$. This finishes the construction.

Answer (score 0):

Pick $a_0$ arbitrary.

Given $a_n$, $f-\operatorname{Id}$ is continuous on the compact $[-|a_n|, |a_n|]$. From $|f-\operatorname{Id}|\not<\max f|_{[-|a_n|, |a_n|]}+1$, we conclude that there exists $a_{n+1}\in\Bbb R$ with $$|f(a_{n+1})-a_{n+1}|\ge \max f|_{[-|a_n|, |a_n|]}+1\ge 1+|f(a_{n})-a_{n}|$$ and clearly $a_{n+1}\notin[-|a_n|,|a_n|]$.

Comment: We don't really need the $f$ to be homeomorphism and the condition f(0)=0. Only $f$ is continuous is enough. Right?

Comment: How did you write the 2nd last line?

Comment: @mathisfun that and the nonboundedness of $f-\operatorname{Id}$

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: I am still not getting the line before last line.